# How to change the range in a WrightMap?

Tags: r

I want to create a WrightMap using the WrightMap Package. I created a Rasch model with the TAM Package.

I found that there is yRange = (a, b) for specification, however, it seems that this is ignored by the function IRT.WrightMap?

Unfortunately, I cannot share data due to privacy restrictions.

Help much appreciated!

My code is:

IRT.WrightMap(Raschmodell, type = "WLE", item.side = "itemClassic", person.side = personDens, main.title = "WrightMap", yrange = c(-3, 3))

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.